# jUnit "Rule" выполняется до "After" аннотации

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Имеется правило для выполнения скриншота если тест упадет:

```
@Rule
public ScreenShotOnFailRule screenShotOnFailRule = new ScreenShotOnFailRule();
```

Так же после каждого теста After:

```
 @After
public void afterTest() {
    WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();
}

/**
 * Finishes browser
 */
public static void finishBrowser() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

При выполнении дает ошибку NullPointerExeption что драйвер не найден для выполнения скриншота.

Comment: Насколько понимаю по статическому методу, вам на самом деле нужен `@AfterClass` - он, возможно, параллельно решит этот race condition

Comment: BeforeClass и AfterClass мне не подходят, т.к браузер не зайрывается после каждого теста. Т,е остается откртытым и продолжеет работу. А мне нужно инициализировать его с каждым тестом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из документации к [`@Rule`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Rule.html):

> The `Statement` passed to the `TestRule` will run any `Before` methods, then the `Test` method, and finally any `After` methods, throwing an exception if any of these fail.

Т.е. `@Rule` умеет только оборачивать последовательность `@Before -> @Test -> @After`, оно не умеет вклиниваться между `@Test` и `@After`, а вам нужно как раз это (выполнить скриншот до того, как сработает `@After`).

Чтобы решить эту проблему, вам нужно поднятие/опускание браузера делать не в `@Before` / `@After`, а в ещё одном `@Rule` (отнаследованном от [`ExternalResource`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html), например). А чтобы эти вещи выполнялись в правильном порядке, придётся воспользоваться [`RuleChain`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html), т.к. в общем случае junit не гарантирует порядок выполнения `@Rule`-полей:

```
public class SomeTests {
    @Rule
    public RuleChain ruleChain = RuleChain
            .outerRule(new WebDriverRule())
            .around(new ScreenShotOnFailRule());

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

`WebDriverRule` можно реализовать как-то так:

```
import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;

public class WebDriverRule extends ExternalResource {
    @Override
    protected void after() {
        WebDriverFactory.finishBrowser();
    }
}
```

Если внутри `WebDriverRule` нужен доступ к каким-то полям класса теста, можно добавить конструктор и передавать значения туда. Или сделать класс вложенным.